# Unable to import BERT model with all packages

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I am trying to learn NLP using BERT. While trying to import bert model and tokenizer in colab. I am facing the below error.

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_LazyModule' from 'transformers.file_utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/file_utils.py)
```

Here is my code

```
!pip install transformers==4.11.3
from transformers import BertModel, BertTokenizer
import torch
```

In order to fix the error.
I tried to upgrade both transformers and torch.

I have tried the solution from the below link:[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66590981/transformer-error-importing-packages-importerror-cannot-import-name-save-st)

Still i am unable to go forward.
Please assist.

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: from transformers import BertModel, BertTokenizer
import torch, i am getting error while running this

Answer (score 0):

Based on these links [1](https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning-flash/issues/630#issuecomment-891031269), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71901851/importerror-cannot-import-name-lazymodule-from-transformers-utils)

This should help -

```
pip install 'lightning-flash[text]' --upgrade
```

Since the code provided by you is not the cause of the error as it runs on Colab when I tried it hence this might be the culprit in your environment

Comment: Thank you, It appears to be the environment issue. I tried to run google colab in  mozila browser instead of chrome. its working now. its unusual, but its working now. Thanks